# Force embedded swf file to open new windows in the current tab

Tags: html, iframe, flash, new-window

I'm trying to prevent some embedded flash files from opening a new window. I would like it to open in the same window the flash file is embedded in.

I thought maybe to put the whole page into an iFrame but this doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin to achieve this effect

There is an example illustrating how to do this for a swf file.

[Rough Demo to help you get started](http://jsfiddle.net/94THq/6/)